# Calling onClick() within an echo'd php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Ive searched high and low for information online for this question and have found absolutely nothing.

I have an admin.php file which gets a list of "unchecked" booking references;

`$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE servStatus = 'unchecked'";`

And for each unchecked iteam thats returned i create a table with the status linked to the corresponding button;

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan=2 style='text-align:center;'>";
        echo "<input name=\"sbutton\" type=\"button\" onClick=\"confirm('confirm.php','content', $fetched_serv_ref)\" value=\"Confirm $fetched_serv_ref\" />";
    echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

On click, i need this to update a status within the DB to 'checked' which is part of the confirm.php file;

```
$query = "UPDATE $table SET `servStatus` = 'checked' WHERE `assign2`.`servRef` = '$sbutton'";
```

and the corospong JS/HXR function is as the below;

```
var hr = createRequest();

function confirm(dataSource, divID, sbutton) {
    if (hr) {
        var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
        var requestbody = "sbutton=" + encodeURIComponent(sbutton);

        hr.open("POST", dataSource, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                obj.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
            } // end if
        }; // end anonymous call-back function
        hr.send(requestbody);
    }
}
```

However, on click, the console is logging "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - admin.html:1

ANY help or guidance would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Most likely `$fetched_serv_ref` is a string, and currently it's unquoted. Notice also, that you're overwriting native global `confirm` method.

Comment: That was it! thanks. Single quotes around the variable worked fine. updated the confirm global. still learning...